# How to combine numbers mathematically?

Tags: c++

There is a way that works with decimal numbers

```
int64_t a = 144;

int64_t b = 5;

a = 10 * a + b;

// a = 1445
```

But what if `b` is greater than the number `9` for example `45` or `147` then this method does not work

how can I make it work with any number, or at least a three-digit number.

Comment: Use decimal logarithm to define the length of `b` and then multiply `a` with 10 power length `b`

Comment: a= (10^number_of_digits_of_b)*a+b

Comment: What should be the result if one of the numbers is negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although there are better ways to achieve that, here is a possible solution :

```
for (int64_t tmp = b; tmp > 0; tmp /= 10)
    a *= 10;
a += b;
```

Be aware of overflows though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop:

```
int64_t intConcat(int64_t a, int64_t b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        return a * 10;
    }
    int64_t t = b;
    while (t != 0)
    {
        a = a * 10;
        t = t / 10;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```